# Using defined function to simplify expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression

$\sqrt{1-6e^{ik}+e^{2ik}}$

I want to simplify this expression by defining

$f(k) \equiv 1-6e^{ik}+e^{2ik}$

So that my output will be

$\sqrt{f(k)}$

Thanks

Comment: Try `(Full)Simplify` with the option `TransformationFunctions ->
 {# /. (1 - 6 E^(i k) + 2^(2 i k) -> f[k]) &, Automatic}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code which will do what you want.

```
Sqrt[1 - 6 Exp[I k] + Exp[2 I k]] /. {1 - 6 Exp[I k] + Exp[2 I k] -> f[k]}
```

There are other ways to do this in Mathematica, but I think this is the simplest.